# Vertical spaces at the last page of section

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am writing a `{book}` using Lyx with `\flushbottom` option. Sometimes some page looks a bit strange because of large vertical spaces, ok. But my question is: Is there an option with says "if a last page of an section is going to be large-spaced, just use `\raggedbottom` locally and let the section end in peace"?

Thanks, Vojta

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Are you referring to the last page of a *chapter* or of a *section*? Please advise.

Comment: Believe me or not, but I originally wrote "Hi" at the beggining and "Thanks, Vojta" at the and, but it has disappeared! Maybe because of the line-breaks between? It's a mystery for me.

Comment: In my kind of document there is a hierarchy: Chapters have sections. So an end of chapter is also end of it's last section.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the following example is to insert

```
\vspace{\fill}
\pagebreak[0]
\vspace{-\fill}
```

at the end of a section.

If there is a page break at `\pagebreak[0]`, then `\vspace{\fill}` fills the page with white space before the page break. The following `\vspace{-\fill}` is discarded at the top of the new page.

Otherwise, without a page break, `\vspace{-\fill}` counteracts `\vspace{\fill}` and the sum is `0pt` without stretch component.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\flushbottom

\newcommand*{\stopsection}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\fill}%
  \pagebreak[0]%
  \vspace{-\fill}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\stopsection

\section{Hello World\\Second Line\\Third Line}

\lipsum[3]
\stopsection

\section{Next section}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I must say that it is not my cup of solution. The problem is not so big, so I will not insert a hack to the ends of all (or some) sections because of it. If there it is nothing that could solve it forever, I i am just going to let it be. Thanks again, Vojta

Comment: Sadly with `\stopsection` page breaks can happen to early. Try e.g. with `\section{section}\lipsum[1]\stopsection\section{section}\lipsum[1-2]` as document. Probably one should combine this with needspace.